# openFl bitmapData.draw crashes

Tags: haxe, openfl

I have a problem with openFl. When I'm using `somebitmapdata.draw(someObject)` build just crushes. I've checked `BitmapData` class, function 'draw' it crashes on line  `__framebuffer = new FilterTexture (gl, width, height, smoothing);` What shall I do to fix it?

Comment: Upgrade your openfl and lime? They changed a few things regarding BitmapDatas recently, might have been fixes.

Comment: Also (in the `BitmapData` class), try a `trace` on all of the variables, before the crash line. See if any of them are null, wrong type?